# Azure Mobile Integration Issue

Tags: java, android, azure, push-notification

I am busy on a project which involves integration into Azure.

I'm attempting to do push notifications through the portal.

When connecting to Azure Mobile  from Android - I keep getting this issue:
Error:(35, 61) error: cannot access ListenableFuture class file for com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture not found

LoginActivity.mClient.getPush().register(gcmRegistrationId);

Has anyone had an issue similar to this?